# Currency value display with space

Tags: crystal-reports, format, currency

We want to put a space in Crystal Reports between a currency symbol and a set of numbers. Crystal ignores the space and just prints the currency symbol, l followed by a numerical value. How can I convert outputs like `£300,000` into `£ 300,000`?

Answer (score 0):

Format your field. Select "Custom Style" in the Format Editor and click the Customize button. Then add a space after your currency symbol in the provided text box:

[image: Add space]